# Estimated Marginal Likelihood in Variational Autoencoder

Tags: variational-bayes

In [Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf) Appendix D, the author proposed an accurate marginal likelihood estimator when the dimensionality of latent space is low (<5).

$$p_{\mathbf{\theta}}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}) \simeq \bigg( \frac{1}{L}\sum^{L}_{l=1} \frac{q(\mathbf{z}^{(l)})}{p_{\mathbf{\theta}}(\mathbf{z}) p_{\mathbf{\theta}}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}|\mathbf{z}^{(l)})}\bigg)^{-1}$$ where $$\mathbf{z} \sim p_{\mathbf{\theta}}(\mathbf{z}|\mathbf{x}^{(i)})$$

However, **when the latent dimensionality is low**, why can't we directly estimate the likelihood as:
$$
p_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}) \simeq \frac{1}{L}\sum_{l=1}^L p_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}^{(i)}|\mathbf{z}^{(l)}), \mathbf{z} \sim p(\mathbf{z})
$$?

Why do we want to sample the latent variables from posterior probability $p_{\theta}(\mathbf{z}|\mathbf{x})$ instead of the prior probability $p_{\theta}(\mathbf{z})$?

Comment: This is correct, however (a) this requires simulating from the prior $p_\theta(\mathbf{z})$ and (b) this should produce more variability in the estimator as many of the simulations should lead to $p_\theta(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z})\approx 0$